# IIS rewrite rule for processing all URLs except given

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Here is the IIS rewriting rule for some URLs to process:

```
    <rule name="rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(word|world|hero|about)[/]?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/info.aspx?id={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

How can I create an opposite rule? For example, I want to process all URLs except "/special", "/escape". This:

```
    <rule name="rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!(special)&amp;?!(escape))[/]?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/info.aspx?id={R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

does not work. "/special" and "/escape" URLs are processed as they should, but other URLs give me 404 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `negate` attribute in this case.

Your rule will become:

```
<rule name="rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(special|escape)/?$" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/info.aspx?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```